# random order for grouped and limited query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
SELECT name,count(*) cnt group by b order by cnt desc limit 10;
```

So I will have a list of items like

```
Name    Count

test     6
test2    4
test6    1
test23   1
test4    1
```

The problem is that there are 1000s results with cnt=1 and I would like to show them randomly, otherwise I'd always show more or less the same for every query. What I would like is a random order on the rows with same cnt value. Is it doable?

Comment: use SELECT DISTINCT cnt, it will give you unique results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RAND()` in order by after your count

```
SELECT name,count(*) cnt from t
 group by b order by cnt desc ,RAND()
 limit 10;
```

So first rows will be ordered by cnt in descending order then for the same value of count (cnt) rows will be ordered randomly

[Sample demo with provided dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/898024/1)

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that. Thanks. Is it expensive? My query is already slow and I don't want to make it slower. (My first idea was to weight items somehow (popularity?), but right now I settle with rand())

Comment: @mobinoob i guess it will be fully covered if you post new question regarding query performance with all the necessary details like table structure,explain plain index information without having these information i can't guess the reason of slow running

Comment: Did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069216/complex-query-takes-too-much-time-transferring